# calculate after get value from select box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the total price by multiply the number of days and price. Another 10 will be added if the they choose yes for breakfast in the selected box. But when I choose 'yes' on breakfast. it does not calculate the breakfast. I have already done the calculation using JavaScript, but it looks like I'm doing it wrong.

Does anyone knows how can I fix this? Thank you so much for your help.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="1" value="10">

<label  for="numofdays">Num.of Days</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="numofdays" id="id1"  value='9'>


<label  for="totalcharges">Total charges</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="totalcharges"  id="id2"  value=myFunction()>

<label  for="bfast">Breakfast</label>
<select name="bfast"   class="formcontrol" > 
  <option >Select option..</option>
  <option id='yes' value='10'>Yes</option>
  <option >No</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
var p2 = document.getElementById("id1").value;
var p3 = document.getElementById("yes").value;

function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById('yes').selected){
       return (p1*p2)+p3;
    }
    else{
        return (p1*p2);
    }
}

document.getElementById("id2").value=myFunction();
```

Comment: where is the element with `id='yes'`

Comment: I've already put the id='yes' but it still does not working.

Comment: that's not how to treat a select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get the value of the select element, not the value of the option.

Something like this:

```
<select id="bfast" name="bfast"   class="formcontrol" > 
    <option value="">Select option..</option>
    <option value='10'>Yes</option>
    <option value='0'>No</option>
</select>
```

....

```
function myFunction() {
    var bfastValue = document.getElementById('bfast').value;
    if(bfastValue){
      return (p1*p2)+Number(bfastValue);
    }
    else{
      return (p1*p2);
    }
}
```

I created you this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/pimboden40/L59aku2o/8/)